# using ExternalLoginCallback for authentication how can I get UserId and UserName ASP.NET MVC5

Tags: authentication, asp.net-mvc-5, owin

I am doing a very basic Login in ASP.NET MVC5 using the following Action:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> ExternalLoginCallback(string returnUrl)
{
    string mid = ExtractMid(returnUrl);

    var loginInfo = await AuthenticationManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync();
    if (loginInfo == null)
    {
        if (mid == null)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Login");
        }
        else
        {
            return RedirectToAction("MobileLoginFailure");
        }
    }

    // Sign in the user with this external login provider if the user already has a login
    var result = await SignInManager.ExternalSignInAsync(loginInfo, isPersistent: false);
    switch (result)
    {
        case SignInStatus.Success:
            if (mid != null)
            {
                return redirectMobile(mid, User.Identity.GetUserName(), User.Identity.GetUserId<int>());
            }
            else
            {
                return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
            }
        case SignInStatus.Failure:
        default:
            return View("ExternalLoginConfirmation");
    }
}
```

I'd expect that after `SignInManager.ExternalSignInAsync(loginInfo, isPersistent: false);` the user will be logged-in so that by:  `redirectMobile(mid, User.Identity.GetUserName(), User.Identity.GetUserId<int>());` I'll be able to get the User's Id and the user's name.
But this is not the case! `User.Identity.GetUserName()` returns `null` and  `User.Identity.GetUserId<int>()` returns `0`.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't say that I know what's going on. However, I did find some solution for my needs.

I added this:

```
var user = await UserManager.FindByEmailAsync(loginInfo.Email);
```

and used the information I needed from there. For completeness -

```
        case SignInStatus.Success:
            if (mid != null)
            {
                var user = await UserManager.FindByEmailAsync(loginInfo.Email);
                if (user == null)
                {
                    return RedirectToAction("MobileLoginFailure");
                }
                else
                {
                    return redirectMobile(mid, user.UserName, user.Id);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
            }
```